# How do we append multiple policies in IAM policy

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I wanted to attach a couple of policies to a role, but noticed that the role can have only 10 policies attached. The below is the existing code i used to create the policies.

```
variable "usernames" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["xxx","yyyy","zzz"]
}

variable "account_id" {
  description = "AWS staging account id"
  type        = string
  default     = "1234567890"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "iam_authentication" {
  for_each = toset(var.usernames)
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "rds-db:connect"
    ]
    resources = flatten(formatlist("arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-1:%s:dbuser:%s/%s", var.account_id, module.rds.yy_resource_id, each.value))
  }
  statement {
    sid    = "1"
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "rds-db:connect"
    ]
    resources = flatten(formatlist("arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-1:%s:dbuser:%s/team", var.account_id, module.rds.yy_resource_id))
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "iam_policy" {
  for_each = toset(var.usernames)
  name     = "iam_authentication_dev_${each.value}"
  path     = "/"
  policy   = data.aws_iam_policy_document.iam_authentication[each.key].json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "iam_policy_attach_to_role" {
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.iam_policy[each.key].arn
  for_each   = toset(var.usernames)
  role       = "ABC"
}
```

I wanted to append all the polices for all the users to a single policy and then add it to the role, in that way i can avoid the 10 limit error. How can i append / merge all policies to one policy?

Comment: Simple: add all the statements to a single IAM policy resource. :)

Comment: yeah right!, but wanted something more dynamic as there are lots of users to be added.

Answer (score 3):

In cases like this, I always try to minimize the amount of policies and combine as most resources into one policy as possible.

Based on your terraform code, I would suggest the following:

```
variable "usernames" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["xxx","yyyy","zzz"]
}

variable "account_id" {
  description = "AWS staging account id"
  type        = string
  default     = "1234567890"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "iam_authentication" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "rds-db:connect"
    ]
    resources = formatlist("arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-1:%s:dbuser:%s/%s", var.account_id, module.rds.yy_resource_id, var.usernames)
  }
  statement {
    sid    = "1"
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "rds-db:connect"
    ]
    resources = formatlist("arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-1:%s:dbuser:%s/team", var.account_id, module.rds.yy_resource_id)
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "iam_policy" {
  name     = "iam_authentication_dev"
  path     = "/"
  policy   = data.aws_iam_policy_document.iam_authentication.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "iam_policy_attach_to_role" {
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.iam_policy.arn
  role       = "ABC"
}
```

This will create one policy with multiple users, like the following example output ("mmm" is just a dummy value for "module.rds.yy_resource_id":

```
# aws_iam_policy.iam_policy will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_policy" "iam_policy" {
      + arn       = (known after apply)
      + id        = (known after apply)
      + name      = "iam_authentication_dev"
      + path      = "/"
      + policy    = jsonencode(
            {
              + Statement = [
                  + {
                      + Action   = "rds-db:connect"
                      + Effect   = "Allow"
                      + Resource = [
                          + "arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-1:1234567890:dbuser:mmm/zzz",
                          + "arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-1:1234567890:dbuser:mmm/yyyy",
                          + "arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-1:1234567890:dbuser:mmm/xxx",
                        ]
                      + Sid      = ""
                    },
                  + {
                      + Action   = "rds-db:connect"
                      + Effect   = "Allow"
                      + Resource = "arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-1:1234567890:dbuser:mmm/team"
                      + Sid      = "1"
                    },
                ]
              + Version   = "2012-10-17"
            }
        )
      + policy_id = (known after apply)
      + tags_all  = {
          + "ew:terraform" = "yes"
        }
    }
```

So now, the only **limit** for the policy is the size itself.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted it to be more dynamic, so tried this.

```
  resource "aws_iam_policy" "iam_policy" {
  name = "iam_authentication"
  path = "/"
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "rds-db:connect"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Resource = concat(
          ["arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-1:${var.account_id}:dbuser:${module.rds.yy_resource_id}/team"],
          [
            for user in var.usernames :
            "arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-1:${var.account_id}:dbuser:${module.rds.yy_resource_id}/${user}"
          ],
        )
      },
    ]
  })
}
```